# "New Partition" option disabled in Disk Management - Can't create new partition on new hard drive

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, partitioning, disk-management

I need some help creating a new partition in a new hard drive. I'm running WinXP.

I know I can only create up to 4 partitions. I have created 4 partitions before, but the hard drive of two of those partitions are broken and are not connected to the pc anymore. Still, the New Partition option is disabled.

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it appears I haven't "initialized" my disk yet. :/

In Disk Management, it will show your disk as

```
Disk N         | ||||black bar||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| 
Basic          |
Uninitialized  |
```

As it says on other sites, all I did was right click on the black bar and to try to select New Partition, but it was disabled. By accident, I right clicked on the left part of the table (the Disk N, Basic, Uninitialized part), and there was an option "Initialize Disk". >.<

Ah well. Leaving this here in case it helps anyone.